# Extract the string between the nth occurrence of two symbols

Tags: r

I'm editing a messy reference list. I'd like to extract the string between the year and the next period.
Original text:

[1] "Acemoglu, D., & Robinson, J. A. (2012). Why nations fail: The origins of power, prosperity, and poverty. Crown Books."
[2] "Adam, S., & Kriesi, H. (2007). The network approach. In Sabatier, P. A. (ed.), Theories of the policy process (2nd Ed.). Cambridge, MA: Westview Press."
[3] "Adams-Webber, J. R. (1969). Cognitive complexity and sociality. British Journal of Social and Clinical Psychology, 8, 211-216."

I'd like to extract the following:

[1] "Why nations fail: The origins of power, prosperity, and poverty."
[2] "The network approach."
[3] "Cognitive complexity and sociality."

I'm using the following code

```
str_extract(df1$References, pattern = "(?<=\\).).*(?=\\.)")
```

And the text extracted did not stop after the first "." It returns:

1] " Why nations fail: The origins of power, prosperity, and poverty. Crown Books"
[2] " The network approach. In Sabatier, P. A. (ed.), Theories of the policy process (2nd Ed.). Cambridge, MA: Westview Press"
[3] " Cognitive complexity and sociality. British Journal of Social and Clinical Psychology, 8, 211-216"

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. You might look at [qdapRegex](https://github.com/trinker/qdapRegex) that contains several approaches to citations (see examples).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using the regex pattern that matches one or more characters that are not a dot (`[.]+`) followed by a `\\`. and this succeeds the `)`, `.` and a space (`\\s`) - wrapped within the regex lookaround

```
library(stringr)
library(tibble)
str_extract(df1$References, "(?<=\\)\\.\\s)[^.]+\\.")
[1] "Why nations fail: The origins of power, prosperity, and poverty." "The network approach."                                           
[3] "Cognitive complexity and sociality."
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(References = c("Acemoglu, D., & Robinson, J. A. (2012). Why nations fail: The origins of power, prosperity, and poverty. Crown Books.", 
"Adam, S., & Kriesi, H. (2007). The network approach. In Sabatier, P. A. (ed.), Theories of the policy process (2nd Ed.). Cambridge, MA: Westview Press.", 
"Adams-Webber, J. R. (1969). Cognitive complexity and sociality. British Journal of Social and Clinical Psychology, 8, 211-216."
)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Base R option with `sub`. Extract the text that comes after `(number)` till the next full stop.

```
x <- c("Acemoglu, D., & Robinson, J. A. (2012). Why nations fail: The origins of power, prosperity, and poverty. Crown Books.", 
       "Adam, S., & Kriesi, H. (2007). The network approach. In Sabatier, P. A. (ed.), Theories of the policy process (2nd Ed.). Cambridge, MA: Westview Press.", 
       "Adams-Webber, J. R. (1969). Cognitive complexity and sociality. British Journal of Social and Clinical Psychology, 8, 211-216.")

sub('.*?\\(\\d+\\)\\.\\s*(.*?)\\..*', '\\1', x)

#[1] "Why nations fail: The origins of power, prosperity, and poverty"
#[2] "The network approach"                                           
#[3] "Cognitive complexity and sociality"
```